# Querying Universal Product Attributes from Sabre

Tags: sabre

Does anyone know how to query UPA (Universal Product Attributes) from Sabre? Where can I find a detailed definition for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You created the same question twice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sabre UPA integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043663/sabre-upa-integration)

Answer (score 0):

There has been an agreement between APTCO and Sabre to distribute Routehappy Rich Content, which includes information on common amenities like Wi-Fi and extra legroom; "universal ticket attributes," meaning the baggage fees and other benefits and restrictions associated with fares; and "universal product attributes," meaning photos, videos and descriptive content to illustrate airline offerings. I don’t believe the same is available just yet but should be coming in soon.

https://apex.aero/2019/10/23/atpco-sabre-amadeus

Also, please refer to the Sabre API guide link mentioned below as well to get more information on the same:- https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/quickstart