# Sabre UPA integration

Tags: sabre

- We would like to use sabre services. We would like to query the available UPAs (Universal Product Attributes) so we could show them to our customers. Currently we would like to show this pre-booking.
- We have registered on the site: https://developer.sabre.com/ found some documentations but not everything is fully clear yet. Do we have a development guide about this topic? If yes, then which document it is?
- When searching for product catalog here: https://developer.sabre.com/product-catalog we could not find anything about this query.
- We also checked the following documentation but it is more about Amenities and UTAs (Universal Ticket Attributes): http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/Merchandising/GAOv3.1_RQRS_UG_TN.pdf

So what we need is a documentation of how to query UPAs (Universal Product Attributes). Could you please help us out?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reference I found for UPA is related to ATPCO and, as far as I know, Sabre does not offer ATPCO content directly. Data goes from ATPCO mainly for shopping and pricing stuff.

If you are new to Sabre, you might want to try checking the *Getting started with Sabre APIs* and then check on the items on the left menu
https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/quickstart